# Minimization under rank constraint of two matrices

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-rank

Let $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}_r$ be the set of matrices of rank at most $r$ and $\|\cdot\|_f$ be the frobenius norm. Consider two matrices $A_1\in\mathbb{R}^{m_1\times n_1}$ and $A_2\in\mathbb{R}^{m_2\times n_2}$.

Is the following statement true?

$$
\min_{X_1\in \mathbb{R}^{m_1\times n_2}_{r{_1}}\atop X2\in \mathbb{R}^{m_2\times n_2}_{r{_2}}} \left(\|A_1-X_1\|_f+\|A_2-X_2\|_f\right)=\min_{X_1\in \mathbb{R}^{m_1\times n_1}_{r{_1}}} \|A_1-X_1\|_f+\min_{X_2\in \mathbb{R}^{m_2\times n_2}_{r{_2}}} \|A_2-X_2\|_f
$$

I'm not sure if I can separate the minimization problem in two.

If anyone has a reference, I would really appreciate it

Comment: If there's no dependency then yes, the statement is true.

Comment: Thanks. However, I need some reference. Not necessarily from this problem, but it can be a general problem.

Comment: It's a trivial claim. Let $f,g$ be two functions of $x$ and $y$ respectively. If $f(x^*) \le f(x) \forall x$ and $g(y^*) \le g(y) \forall y$ then $f(x^*)+g(y^*) \le f(x)+g(y) \forall x,y$